# When you find endorsement in an arXiv, is it certain to get the research published?

Tags: arxiv

I read some questions on this platform and found that arXiv does not review research as in one of the questions here. Does this mean that the only obstacle to publishing the paper is endorsement only

Comment: Posting on arXiv is not publishing. You need to submit the paper to a journal and go through peer review to be published.

Comment: @astronat I know of course

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly.  There is a moderation process to weed out fakery and nonsense. It isn’t a full review though.

Comment: And as a preprint service, at least some of us don't consider uploading to arxiv as 'publishing'...

Comment: no, you 'acquire' copyright when you create the document.

Comment: If somebody hacks your computer and steals your unpublished great American novel and proceeds to publish it, well, they have violated your copyright and will be found liable. You take a (film) picture and have not developed it yet - you own the copyright regardless.

Comment: @DanRomik, a poor choice of words, I'll admit. But putting something on arXiv _is_ publishing by the most common definition of the word  (making generally available). It also supports a claim of priority (potentially) and gives you a way to _defend against_ copyright infringement. That was my intention.